# Problem testing solidity transaction in hardhat with chai

Tags: testing, solidity, chai, hardhat

I wrote a contract for crowdfunding and I'm having troubling the last test:

```
 it("should allow the owner of the campaign to withdraw funds if the campaign is successful", async () => {
    const target = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
    await contract
      .connect(aliceAccount)
      .createCampaign(
        "Test Campaign",
        "Test Description",
        target,
        "testimage.jpg"
      );
    await contract
      .connect(bobAccount)
      .donateToCampaign(0, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1") });
  
    const campaign = await contract.campaigns(0);
    const ownerInitialBalance = await aliceAccount.getBalance();
    const tx = await contract.connect(aliceAccount).withdrawFunds(0);
    const receipt = await tx.wait()
   const ownerFinalBalance = await aliceAccount.getBalance();
    
    const result = ownerInitialBalance.add(target).sub(receipt.gasUsed)
   
    expect(campaign.status).to.equal(2);
    expect(ownerFinalBalance).to.equal(result);
   
  });
```

the error output in the console:

```
AssertionError: expected 10000997823969736606208 to equal 10000997858212031010378. The numerical values of the given "ethers.BigNumber" and "ethers.BigNumber" inputs were compared, and they differed.
      + expected - actual

      -10000997823969736606208
      +10000997858212031010378
```

It appears to be a difference in the gas used for the transaction?

Comment: I believe it is the order of the code, the line `const ownerFinalBalance = await aliceAccount.getBalance();` is ran before the `tx` is successfully mined on the chain, i.e. your balance is fetched before the withdrawal. If you switch the order of the two lines, `const receipt = await tx.wait()` with it, it should work.

Comment: that's correct! but still same problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
const gasUsed = receipt.effectiveGasPrice.mul(receipt.cumulativeGasUsed)
expect(campaign.status).to.equal(2);
expect(ownerFinalBalance).to.equal(ownerInitialBalance.add(target).sub(gasUsed));
```